Trouble customizing walker_nav_menu for BS5 navbar
I have tumbled around in the rabbit hole, try'd different solutions for my BS5 main navbar with a WordPress Theme.
Have build a extended walker_nav_menu class for wp_nav_menu(), where playing around with start_el or end_lvl functions.
My end_lvl function seems not to get fired or something, as you see in the code below. There should be added an extra element to the list, containing languagebare for switching between 2 languages.
Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Code in functions.php
class BS5_MainMenu extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{

  public function start_el(&$output, $data_object, $depth = 0, $args = null, $current_object_id = 0)
  {
    $item = $data_object; // use more descriptive name for use within this method.

    $frontpageID = get_option('page_on_front');

    if ($item->post_parent != 0 || $item->ID == $frontpageID) {
      return;
    }

    $itemUrl = get_permalink($item);

    $children = $this->getChildren($item->ID);

    $_liCssClass = "nav-item";
    $_aCssClass = "nav-link";

    if (count($children)) {
      $_liCssClass .= " dropdown";
      $_aCssClass .= " dropdown-toggle";
    }

    $output .= '<li class="' .  $_liCssClass . '">';

    if (!empty($itemUrl) && $itemUrl != '#') {
      $output .= '<a href="' . $itemUrl . '" class="' . $_aCssClass . '" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">';
    } else {
      $output .= '<span>';
    }

    $output .= $item->post_title;

    if (!empty($itemUrl) && $itemUrl != '#') {
      $output .= '</a>';
    } else {
      $output .= '</span>';
    }

    $output .= $this->renderChildrenDropdownHtml($item->ID);
  }

  public function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = null)
  {
    $otherLanguage = $this->get_other_languages()[0];

    $output .= '<li class="nav-item mx-4">';
    $output .= '<a class="nav-link nav-translate" href="' . $otherLanguage->permalink . '">' . $otherLanguage->res_label . ' <span>' . $otherLanguage->displaylanguage . '</span></a>';
    $output .= '</li></ul>';
  }

  private function get_other_languages()
  {
    $_all = get_available_languages();
    $_other = array();
    $_current = get_locale();

    foreach ($_all as $result) {
      if ($_current == $result) {
        continue;
      }

      $_lang_of_result = explode("_", $result)[0];

      $_obj = new stdClass();
      $_obj->displaylanguage = Locale::getDisplayLanguage($_lang_of_result, $_lang_of_result);
      $_obj->permalink = get_msls_permalink($result);
      $_obj->flagurl = get_msls_flag_url($result);
      $_obj->res_label = $_lang_of_result == "da" ? "Skift til" : "Switch to";

      $_other[] = $_obj;
    }

    return $_other;
  }

  private function renderChildrenDropdownHtml($post_id)
  {
    if (!$post_id) {
      return false;
    }

    $children = $this->getChildren($post_id);
    if (!count($children)) {
      return false;
    }

    $html = '<ul class="dropdown-menu">';

    foreach ($children as $child) {
      $html .= '<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="' . get_permalink($child) . '">' . $child->post_title . '</a></li>';
    }

    $html .= '</ul>';
    return $html;
  }

  private function getChildren($post_id)
  {
    if (!$post_id) {
      return false;
    }

    $args = array(
      'post_parent' => $post_id,
      'post_type' => 'any',
      'numberposts' => -1,
      'post_status' => 'any'
    );
    return get_children($args);
  }
}

In my parts/header.php
<nav class="navbar navbar-main navbar-expand-lg highlighted" data-bs-theme="dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/index.html">
        <img src="<?php echo esc_url(get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/logo.svg'); ?>" height="70" />
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#main-navbar"
        aria-controls="main-navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Visning af navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-navbar">
        <?php

        wp_nav_menu([
          'theme_location' => 'MainMenu',
          'menu_class' => 'navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0',
          'container' => 'ul',
          'walker' => new BS5_MainMenu()
        ]);

        ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

I have tried different things, found on Google

In a custom walker class, if you override end_lvl, you also need to append your modifications to the output after calling the parent's end_lvl. If the parent method is not called, the default behavior for ending levels in wp_nav_menu will be skipped.
For your end_lvl function try the following
public function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = null) {
    // Call the parent to maintain default behavior
    parent::end_lvl($output, $depth, $args);

    // Append the language bar after the submenu closes
    if ($depth === 0) { // Only add at the top-level menu
        $otherLanguage = $this->get_other_languages()[0];

        $output .= '<li class="nav-item mx-4">';
        $output .= '<a class="nav-link nav-translate" href="' . $otherLanguage->permalink . '">'
                . $otherLanguage->res_label . ' <span>' . $otherLanguage->displaylanguage . '</span></a>';
        $output .= '</li>';
    }
}


Unfortunately it gives the same result, end_lvl only prints .
I have taken your version of end_lvl.
Does it matter if I run it through XAMPP

parent::end_lvl($output, $depth, $args); try removing this and close it yourself ? $output .= ''; ?

nope, still nothing, just </ul>
